# JDK 11 is not reflecting

Tags: java-11

I have installed jdk 11 but when i am checking the version from command prompt it is showing the jdk 1.8 only. 
What I have tried is :
1. downloaded the jdk-11.0.7_windows-x64_bin.exe from oracle website
2. installed the same (my system is also 64 bit) 
3. Edited the path variable
4. restarted the system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is probably because you have multiple java version installed in your system. Just uninstall all the previous version from your system with only the required one. Check the version installed in your system. This will show you the new java version installed in your system.

Comment: Thanks @Gaurav, I uninstalled the previous versions and it is working now

Comment: I uninstalled the previous versions and it still says "java is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Answer (score 0):

You can also go without installing by downloading zip file extract it place it in you c:/program files / java 
and set java_home in environmental variables

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue comes with me , in my system there are java jdk 8 and jdk 12 is
installed already ,and i need jdk 11 for work with sonarcube so i also install it
So after uninstall previous jdk version issue is resolved.
For uninstall jdk :
Go to control panel ->program->program and features -> right click on jdk program
->Uninstall.